# PHP: make the "connection to DB" script once for all

Tags: php, pdo

I have working PHP scripts as shown below:-

main.php file:

```
<?php 
include'../scripts/pdoMysqlPhpScript1.php'; 
?>
```

pdoMysqlPhpScript1.php file:

```
<?php
     include 'login.php';
     $dbh-> query('use testdata1970_10');
     foreach($dbh->query('call getallusers();') as $row)
?>
```

login.php file:

```
<?php// PDO is used
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; Port=3306';
$user = 'root';
$pswd = '';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd,
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
?>
```

It is working.

However, if I include login.php in main.php and remove login.php from pdoMysqlPhpScript1.php. It did not work.

Why is that and how do I ensure that login.php is used once so that I will not need to use it again for every service from many different php files or stored procedures until it is closed at the end of script?

for example:-

main.php file:

```
<?php

     include 'login.php'; //scripts inside:- $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd,....);
     include 'fileA.php'; //scripts inside:- $dbh = query('use storedprocedure');
     include 'fileB.php'; //scripts inside:- $dbh -> query ('select x from xtable'); 
     include 'fileC.php'; //scripts inside:- $stmt = $dbh->prepare('select name, value from test where name=:what');   
     include 'fileD.php'; //scripts inside:- $dbh = query('select testtable()');
     include 'fileE.php'; //scripts inside:- $stmt = $dbh->prepare('select name, value from test'); 
?>
```

Please advise 
Thanks
Clement

Comment: You say "It did not work", but what did not work? Was there an error message of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I ensure that login.php is used once so that I will not need to use it again for every service from many different php files or stored procedures until it is closed at the end of script?

Just do it like you're doing it now - include it at the very top of your main script.
Only make sure you are addressing `$dbh` variable within global scope. Otherwise (i.e. within a function) you have to make it accessible using `global $dbh;`